# Runge-Kutta 4 for solving systems of ODEs Python

Tags: python, differential-equations, scientific-computing

I wrote code for Runge-Kutta 4 for solving system of ODEs. 
It works fine for 1-D ODE but when I try to solve `x'' + kx = 0` I have a problem trying to define a vectorial function:

Let `u1 = x` and `u2 = x' = u1'`, then the system looks like:

```
u1' = u2
u2' = -k*u1
```

If `u = (u1,u2)` and `f(u, t) = (u2, -k*u1)`, then we need to solve:

```
u' = f(u, t)
```

```py
def f(u,t, omega=2):
    u, v = u
    return np.asarray([v, -omega**2*u])
```

My entire code is:

```
import numpy as np

def ode_RK4(f, X_0, dt, T):    
    N_t = int(round(T/dt))
    #  Create an array for the functions ui 
    u = np.zeros((len(X_0),N_t+1)) # Array u[j,:] corresponds to the j-solution
    t = np.linspace(0, N_t*dt, N_t + 1)
    # Initial conditions
    for j in range(len(X_0)):
        u[j,0] = X_0[j]
    # RK4
    for j in range(len(X_0)):
        for n in range(N_t):
            u1 = f(u[j,n] + 0.5*dt* f(u[j,n], t[n])[j], t[n] + 0.5*dt)[j]
            u2 = f(u[j,n] + 0.5*dt*u1, t[n] + 0.5*dt)[j]
            u3 = f(u[j,n] + dt*u2, t[n] + dt)[j]
            u[j, n+1] = u[j,n] + (1/6)*dt*( f(u[j,n], t[n])[j] + 2*u1 + 2*u2 + u3)
    
    return u, t

def demo_exp():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    def f(u,t):
        return np.asarray([u])

    u, t = ode_RK4(f, [1] , 0.1, 1.5)
    
    plt.plot(t, u[0,:],"b*", t, np.exp(t), "r-")
    plt.show()
    
def demo_osci():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    def f(u,t, omega=2):
        # u, v = u Here I've got a problem
        return np.asarray([v, -omega**2*u])
    
    u, t = ode_RK4(f, [2,0], 0.1, 2)
    
    for i in [1]:
        plt.plot(t, u[i,:], "b*")
    plt.show()
```

In advance, thank you.

Comment: What python version are you using? What does `1/6` evaluate to?

Comment: Could you explain your motivation for the component-wise application of the RK4 steps? And do you know what broadcasting means in the context of numpy arrays? That is, what happens when you add a vector and a scalar?

Comment: I’m using Python 3.8. The 1/6 factor arise from the derivation of the model.

Comment: You can’t add vector and a scalar. But I think i am not doing that. The function f is an array, then I add [j] for each solution.

Comment: But you do. When you select a component you make `u1` be a scalar. In the next stage you add this scalar to the state vector. Replace the RK4 step with the Euler step and contemplate the logistics of your algorithm for a small number of time steps, what components of the state vectors are defined, which ones get set, which results are valid and which invalid due to not available inputs. In the end, you have inserted some complications that are unnecessary and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path, but when applying time-integration methods such as RK to vector valued ODEs, one essentially does the exact same thing as in the scalar case, just with vectors.

Thus, you skip the `for j in range(len(X_0))` loop and associated indexation and you make sure that you pass initial values as vectors (numpy arrays).

Also cleaned up the indexation for `t` a little and stored the solution in a list.

```
import numpy as np

def ode_RK4(f, X_0, dt, T):    
    N_t = int(round(T/dt))
    # Initial conditions
    usol = [X_0]
    u = np.copy(X_0)
    
    tt = np.linspace(0, N_t*dt, N_t + 1)
    # RK4
    for t in tt[:-1]:
        u1 = f(u + 0.5*dt* f(u, t), t + 0.5*dt)
        u2 = f(u + 0.5*dt*u1, t + 0.5*dt)
        u3 = f(u + dt*u2, t + dt)
        u = u + (1/6)*dt*( f(u, t) + 2*u1 + 2*u2 + u3)
        usol.append(u)
    return usol, tt

def demo_exp():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    def f(u,t):
        return np.asarray([u])

    u, t = ode_RK4(f, np.array([1]) , 0.1, 1.5)
    
    plt.plot(t, u, "b*", t, np.exp(t), "r-")
    plt.show()
    
def demo_osci():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    def f(u,t, omega=2):
        u, v = u 
        return np.asarray([v, -omega**2*u])
    
    u, t = ode_RK4(f, np.array([2,0]), 0.1, 2)
    
    u1 = [a[0] for a in u]
    
    for i in [1]:
        plt.plot(t, u1, "b*")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem was the ' for j in range...' :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The model is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iHw5.jpg)

From the Langtangen’s book Programming for Computations - Python.